# Rsync dry-run statistics- Different statistics after executing 'cp' and 'rsync' commands

Tags: linux, rsync

In order to generate some random files, I have created a script which is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

for dir in `seq 1 10`
do
        mkdir /root/mandar/RsyncSrc/$dir
        cd /root/mandar/RsyncSrc/$dir
        for file in `seq 11 20`
        do
                touch /root/mandar/RsyncSrc/$dir/$file
        done
done
```

Thus, the contents of `/root/mandar/RsyncSrc` directory looks like:

```
1  10  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  mkfiles.sh
```

**Case 1 (With `cp` command):**

I execute the following command in order to sync `/root/mandar/RsyncSrc` with `/root/mandar/RsyncDst` directory:

```
cp -R /root/mandar/RsyncSrc/* /root/mandar/RsyncDst/
```

Contents of `/root/mandar/RsyncDst` directory:

```
1  10  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  mkfiles.sh
```

Now, I run the `rsync` `dry-run` in order to get list of affected files as follows:

```
rsync -avzm --stats --safe-links --dry-run --ignore-existing --human-readable /root/mandar/RsyncSrc/*  /root/mandar/RsyncDst/ > test.log
```

Contents of `test.log` file:

```
building file list ... done
1/
10/
2/
3/
4/
5/
6/
7/
8/
9/

Number of files: 112
Number of files transferred: 0
Total file size: 234 bytes
Total transferred file size: 0 bytes
Literal data: 0 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 926
File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 963
Total bytes received: 42

sent 963 bytes  received 42 bytes  2.01K bytes/sec
total size is 234  speedup is 0.23 (DRY RUN)
```

**Case 2 (With `rsync` command):**

I deleted everything from `/root/mandar/RsyncDst` and executed following command to sync the data:

```
rsync -avzm --stats --safe-links --ignore-existing --human-readable /root/mandar/RsyncSrc/*  /root/mandar/RsyncDst/
```

And then re-run the `dry-run` as follows:

```
rsync -avzm --stats --safe-links --dry-run --ignore-existing --human-readable /root/mandar/RsyncSrc/*  /root/mandar/RsyncDst/ > test.log
```

This time, contents of `test.log` are:

```
building file list ... done

Number of files: 112
Number of files transferred: 0
Total file size: 234 bytes
Total transferred file size: 0 bytes
Literal data: 0 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 926
File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 933
Total bytes received: 12

sent 933 bytes  received 12 bytes  1.89K bytes/sec
total size is 234  speedup is 0.25 (DRY RUN)
```

1. Why is it not showing any files/directories in the log file, in case of `rsync` (case 2)?
2. If I need to show file listing in the log with `rsync` (case 2), what am I supposed to do?

Comment: Which version of rsync are you using? I get a different output.

Comment: rsync-3.0.6-9.el6_4.1.x86_64

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using the `-a` option when you do the copy with `rsync` and you do not use the -a option with `cp`. This results in the timestamps on the `cp` copied files not being preserved.

*PS giving rsync additional `-v` options results in additional output. Although I am using rsync  version 3.1.0  protocol version 31, which has a slightly different output report, it has the same results as yours. When I used -a option on the initial `cp` copy, rsync outputs the same on my rsyncDstCp and rsyncDstRsync directories.*